# In Hibernate OneToMany mapping

Tags: hibernate

what we have to specify in the Optional Element "**mappedBy**".Is it the table_name of specific model or Classname?
**Which is correct?**

This

> @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy =
>   "AdminUser")  private List sessions;

OR this.....?

> @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy =
>   "admin_user")     private List sessions;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relationship is bidirectional, the `mappedBy` element must be used to specify the relationship **field or property** of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks... :)
Specified like this
mappedBy = "adminUser"